# Java/Tomcat. After some time there are exceptions of Class loading

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war, classloading

Upon deployment my application works but after some time it happens that there are `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at javax/imageio/impl/IIOInvalidTreeException at  com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriterSpi.createWriterInstance`

It is a maven built war file deployed in Tomcat so there is no tampering with the supplied jar-files. The time it works before the problem appears vary between the occasions. By doing

`$ mvn dependency:tree`

and grep-ing for "image" I can with certainity say that the only jar-files included are

`com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.4.0 com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-jpeg2000:jar:1.4.0`

I would like to know if this should be an impossible situation? Could this happen with errors by programming? There are also considerations in the deployment environment but I do not want to point to those before I have done some work with my part of this.

I am mostly dissappointed with the lack of determinism of this.

Comment: Have you tried grep-ing with **imagio** instead? Also, have you tracked down if any specific API call is causing this error?

Comment: The not found class is a javax and the github docs warns that some classes may exist in other deps. Also it says that [same functionality is provided by java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html). try adding `-verbose:class` to the jvm options to spot which jar is used to load the class.

Comment: Grepping for imag makes no more hits in the dependency tree than the ones described.

Comment: And grepping for jai adds

javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile